# Push notifications stops working after a while

Tags: mobilepush, mobilepush-android, push-notification, push

I am implementing the SFMC Push notifications on our app and we successfully implemented it (multiple sdk, contact key registration and stuff works okay) but we noticed that after a while (hours or 1, 2 days) the notification stops working but Marketing Cloud says the send was successful.

Searching for the docs and stuff we noticed that this issue is known because of how the notification is sent (as a data payload) and the notification is not processed by the app if it's on background, but notification payload works normally on background.

Is it a known issue and we just need to deal with it or is there any way to overcome it and force notifications to reach the app?

OBS.: looks like it only happens on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has become more aggressive about "quieting" your device. The Marketing Cloud does not currently (as of 20230719) offer a way to mark a message as a `priority` message.

The messages *will* be delivered, but it often requires the user to wake their phone, unlock their phone, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
We did some tests here too and noticed that behaviour of Android hibernating apps and stuff. Is there any reason to Marketing Cloud not send notification messages and only data messages?

When sending notification messages directly from Firebase it works normally (as it should) but data messages (the way SFMC sends the push currently, afaik) we have that behaviour of not receiving messages on background (or not even receiving at all).

Comment: Open a Voice of Customer request through your Account Executive. It's the only avenue to get this changed.